# how to display single array data in multiple sections --javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have two sections.. section 1:- display the latest 3, section 2:- display all data.. is it possible with single array data?

```js
let t_p_data = [
    {id: 1,}, {id: 2,}, {id: 3,}, {id: 4,}, {id: 5,},
];
let paymentsData = $('.payments-data');
let paymentsList = paymentsData.innerHTML;
for (let p_data of t_p_data.slice(-3).reverse()) {
    paymentsList += `<tr><td><a href="" target="">${p_data.id}</a></td></tr>  `
}
paymentsData.append(paymentsList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody class="payments-data"><tr><td><h1>Latest Three</h1></td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody class="payments-data"><tr><td><h1>All</h1></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice, reverse, map, and then join for *latest*, and just map and join for *all*.

You can use jQuery's [`.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) to add the elements directly after the 1st tr. To add the new content after the last child use `tr:last-child`.

```js
const t_p_data = [
  {id: 1,}, {id: 2,}, {id: 3,}, {id: 4,}, {id: 5,},
];

const createItem = ({ id }) =>
  `<tr><td><a href="" target="">${id}</a></td></tr>`;
    

$('.payments-data.latest tr').after(
  t_p_data
    .slice(-3)
    .reverse()
    .map(createItem)
    .join('')
);

$('.payments-data.all tr').after(
  t_p_data
    .map(createItem)
    .join('')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody class="payments-data latest"><tr><td><h1>Latest Three</h1></td></tr></tbody>
    <tbody class="payments-data all"><tr><td><h1>All</h1></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```